# Laravel - Domain API?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure something out. I want to make a page where a user can check for domain names and if they're available or not. I'm asking for advice because I don't know where to look. TransIP does have an API but I can't understand their documentation. What can I do? I want to make this work in laravel

Answer (score 0):

There are many API wrappers you can grab from github, here is one I found on a google search. https://github.com/verschoof/transip-api

Just install with composer, put your login and private key in your .env perhaps and then include it in whatever file you want.

```
$client = new Transip\Client(env('TRANSIP_LOGIN'), env('TRANSIP_KEY'), true);
$domainApi  = $client->api('domain');
$domainInfo = $domainApi->getInfo('user-input-domain.com'); 
$status = $domainApi->checkAvailability();
```

I would put env variables into a config file and access with `config('key')` but this is a basic example.